# Question about the meaning of 内外

Tags: translation

I can't figure out the meaning of 内外 and the nuance of 親族 because of it in the following passage. I think I'm more or less understand the basic concept of 内 and 外. I also looked through the dictionary and it is written that 内外 could mean incide the country and outside. But could the author be talking about the people from family and outsiders in this context with it? One line after it, the author uses the word 親族, that's where I lost it. So is he talking about the other family members, who are the enemies of the stepfather? Or means the situation itself, where his sole daughter has to inherit everything?

Fast translation:
Being known for his shrewdness, stepfather made lots of enemies (incide the country and outside/from his family and outsiders)

> 辣腕で知られた義父は**内外**で様々な恨みを買っていた。彼が死去した今、その責は全て一人娘である希へと降り掛かったのだ。陰謀渦巻く宮廷のように、主人公は遺産や名誉などを巡る泥臭い権力争いの渦中へと巻き込まれていく。
>   主人公は誓う。 そう、主人公は愛すべき妻ーー希を**親族**の罠から救うべく闘うのだ。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

内外 can mean the outside and inside of any organization. It can be 国内と国外, 社内と社外, 学校内と学校外, and so on, depending on the context.

In this example, this 内外 is probably 社内と社外 or 家庭内と家庭外, but if you can't determine, don't worry. 内外で sometimes just means 'in many places' or 'everywhere'.

Answer (score 1):

"内外で" *without* any specification implies "domestic and abroad."

The context of the excerpt does not specify what is meant by "内" and "外", but methinks it is ridiculous to assume that the authour is talking about international affairs.

I guess he/she should have chosen more appropriate expressions like "方々で", "あちこちで", "至る所で" and so on.